# Проблема с mysql connect() и end() (node JS)

Tags: mysql, node.js, setinterval

Сегодня весь вечер пытался решить дурацкую проблему с закрытием соединения.
Есть функция, которая запускается через setInterval (код будет ниже). И в этой функции каждый раз создается подключение к БД и закрывается. Но это так должно быть. На деле если добавлять в конец функции con.end(), то при следующем подключении выдает:

> Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.

Если не закрывать подключение то в следующий раз оно просто скажет:

> Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.

Все бы ничего, я не дурак (вроде) и пытался сделать весь этот setTimeout внутри большого подключения, которое происходило бы после запуска файла, да вот только у меня timeout на 10 минут и оно дает ошибку о том, что долгое время подключения (пример не приведу, тк придется переделать код обратно).

У меня есть мысли с .then, после куска con.connect, но не получилось, и я решил не делать костыли, и просто спросить.

Было бы замечательно узнать в чем дело, ведь в этой теме я новенький.

***Кусок кода с сервера:***

```
let bodyOld = '';

const sendReq = () => {

// send request to gitHub
const request = https.request(options, res => {

    // get all request data from git and put it in 'body'
    let body = '';
    res.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk;
    });

    // if we have new data ( != data from DB )
    if (bodyOld != JSON.stringify(body)) {
        // bodyOld = JSON.stringify(body);
        // connect to mysql
        con.connect(err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error ' + err)
            } else {

                // dell all old data in DB
                let sql = "DELETE FROM info";
                con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
                    err ? console.log('Error ' + err) :
                        console.log("All old data was deleted.");
                })

                // parce data and put in DB
                res.on('end', () => {
                    body = JSON.parse(body);
                    body.forEach(repo => {
                        let sql = "INSERT INTO info (name, url, description, language, create_at, last_update, size) VALUES ('" +
                            repo.name + "', '" + repo.html_url + "', '" + repo.description + "', '" + repo.language + "', '" +
                            repo.created_at.substring(0, 10) + "', '" + repo.updated_at.substring(0, 10) + "', '" + repo.size + "')";

                        con.query(sql, (err, result) => {
                            err ? console.log('Error ' + err) :
                                console.log("One new record.");
                        })
                    })
                })
            }
        })
        // con.end();
    }else{
        console.log('It alreadey update.');
        request.end();
        return;
    }
})

// check err
request.on('error', e => {
    console.error('Error is: ' + e);
});

request.end();
}

// setInterval every 10 minutes
setInterval(sendReq, 600);
```

Comment: почему бы не оставить одно подключение к mysql, оно же в принципе ничего не тянет, зачем каждые 10 мин реконектиться?

Comment: Потому что оно разрывается. На сколько я понял что-то типо timeout-а происходит. Вообще я решил проблему через пулл соединений.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение этой проблемы через mysql.createPool.

***Создаем пулл:***

```
// connect ot mysql data for PC
const optionsMysql = {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: 'guthub_proj'
}

const pool = mysql.createPool(optionsMysql)
```

***Теперь при каждом запросе можно просто вытягивать из пула соединение:***

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, con) {
    //code here...
}
```

На сколько я понял его можно не закрывать. И это то что мне было нужно.